# restoring ubuntu in dual-boot setup after grub screen "GNU GRUB version 2.02" (mistakenly deleted partition)

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, partitioning, grub

I have an ASUS rog series laptop. Previously, I installed both Windows 10 and ubuntu 20.04 in a dual-boot setup.

As I mostly work in remote servers, I didn't use Ubuntu on my laptop for a while. Last night, I checked my device partition (as my drives were getting almost full), and deleted a previous partition to create a new one for windows.

[image: disk management]

After the restart, I found the laptop was not booting correctly and showing the following screen.
[image: grub screen]

Now, most of the data was on windows, so I pressed F2 and went to bios settings, and decided to change the boot order.

[image]

Now, after restarting the laptop started with windows directly. Is there any way I can get into ubuntu as I didn't backup the data?

Comment: There is NO Ubuntu in your drives currently. Very likely you removed the Ubuntu partition and reformatted it as NTFS. The first partition is not "Ubuntu" (nor "Windows"), it's the ESP (EFI System Partition) where the bootloaders reside. That you removed Ubuntu doesn't automatically remove its efi files in the ESP, reason why before it tried to boot Grub. Likewise, just because there's still an Ubuntu bootloader doesn't mean you can still boot Ubuntu. Any data there is very likely unrecoverable now.

Comment: Makes sense, @ChanganAuto. Is there a way to recover the first and last partition?

Comment: No, there isn't, that's what I said before.

Comment: First of all, be sure any files of value are backed up. Especially anytime partitions are involved. You can boot to an Ubuntu Live CD/USB. If there are any remaining Linux files, you should be able to see them.

Comment: Thanks, @user3169 this is helpful.